# How to deduplicate an array with substring variations where one substring has precedence over another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing

I have a dataset similar to this:
http://pastie.org/private/3u1reg72nnjfsgqzgqzwra

The list is a set of filenames that need to be processed.  When a filename that has a substring of `10u` exists along with one with a substring of `2u`, the filename with `10u` in it has a subset of data from the file with the `2u` substring.  In other words, when you have something like:

```
20021203_V9ut_2u.txt 
20021203_V9ut_10u.txt 
    or 
V9cd_2u.txt
V9cd_10u.txt
```

the `20021203_V9ut_10u.txt` and `V9cd_10u.txt` should be removed from the list and only the filenames with `1u` should remain in the list.

I've attempted a few various methods, but they all feel too much like C or hackish.  I have also thought about splitting the string and then building a hash with the values of the `1u` or `10u` and then if a key with a `10u` value in it exists, replace it with `1u`, else discard  and then remap the hash to an array for processing the file contents.

What is the "best" or most ruby way to do this and can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file list sometimes contains files that don't have a perfect match of 2u and 10u this will help you. It removes the 10u files, if and only if there is a corresponding 2u file, leaves it in the resulting list otherwise.

```
files = %w(20021203_V9ut_2u.txt 
20021203_V9ut_10u.txt 
V9cd_2u.txt
V9cd_10u.txt
test1_2u.txt
thing2_10u.txt)

# Reverse sort them if they aren't already that way

files = files.sort {|a,b| b <=> a }

puts files.inspect

scrubbed_files = []
files.each_with_index { |f,i| 
  scrubbed_files << f unless f =~ /(.*)_10u\.(.*)/ && files[i-1] =~ /#{$1}_2u\.#{$2}/
}

puts scrubbed_files.inspect
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an array of `all_filenames` as strings:

```
filenames_2u = all_filenames.reject!{ |f| f =~ /10u/ } # edited to be actual working ruby
```

**edit** If the file you provided is what you're working with:

```
all_filenames = IO.readlines('filenames.txt')
```

Comment: Presently what you have only removes the elements in the array with 10u present.  I need to actually only remove 10u when the remainder of the string (filename) matches and a filename with 1u is present.  Please review the original explanation where it shows that when you have, for example: V9cd_2u.txt & V9cd_10u.txt - the V9cd_10u.txt should only then be removed.

Comment: I understand now. Let me see if I can come up with something.

Comment: The other answer from @ctcherry worked great.  You're certainly welcome to work on it further or come up with a different solution if you'd like!  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: No problem, I'll move on though, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This way is more fun:

```
a.map {|x| x.split(/_/)}.group_by {|x| x[0...-1]}.map {|_,xx| xx.sort_by {|x| x.last.to_i}.first.join("_")}
```

That is, split the names into arrays at the underscores, group these by the stems (the parts up to the last underscore), then for each group sort the names by the integer versions of the last bit and take the first one.

This will work for any Xu numbering scheme, so if you had 2u and 5u and 10u you'd get the 2u version, and if you had 10u and 20u you'd get the 10u.

`group_by` is cool.

Comment: Pretty slick.  I'll look into this.